# have ipython open editor at an error in a script

Tags: python, ipython

When running a script in Ipython (with %run) and there is an error in the script, is it possible to open an editor at the line of the error or have an open editor jump to that line?

Answer (score 0):

Automatically this is not happening, although one could implement something like that. The question is, what would be the correct file to open? The backtrace will reveal all possible files in which the functions raised the error. In a large project, it would not be clear in which file the error is, is it with the caller or callee who made the error?
Most advanced IDEs e.g. eclipse with pydev allow direct jumps to the lines and function calls, so it is covered there.

on an ipython level you could do

```
%edit file_named_in_error.py
```